# What is the reach of a Tiny creature, when it's not listed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, reach

The [intro to the Bestiary](http://legacy.aonprd.com/bestiary/introduction.html) says:

> Space/Reach: The creature's space and reach—**if the creature's space and reach are standard (one 5-foot square and a reach of 5 feet), this line is omitted**.

But then [Big and Little Creatures in Combat](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Big%20and%20Little%20Creatures%20in%20Combat&Category=Combat) says:

> A Tiny creature typically occupies a space only 2-1/2 feet across, so four can fit into a single square. 25 Diminutive creatures or 100 Fine creatures can fit into a single square. **Creatures that take up less than 1 square of space typically have a natural reach of 0 feet, meaning they can’t reach into adjacent squares.** They must enter an opponent’s square to attack in melee.

Meanwhile, now that I've started looking, I'm finding many Tiny creatures that don't have a listed Space or Reach, e.g. [Silvanshee](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Silvanshee), [Clockwork Familiar](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Clockwork%20Familiar), [Animated Object](http://legacy.aonprd.com/bestiary/animatedObject.html)

It seems most reasonable to me that cat-sized creatures have 0' reach unless they have rules text to state otherwise (and the second quote seems to agree)...but I'll admit the first quote seems to say otherwise. Is there an official ruling as to what the reach is for Tiny (or smaller) creatures without a listed reach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### They have no reach (or 0 ft reach)

The rules found on [Big and Little Creatures](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Big%20and%20Little%20Creatures%20in%20Combat&Category=Combat) in combat are the default for Tiny (or smaller) creatures, there are no other exceptions. Except, of course, when a specific creature has a natural weapon with a reach larger than normal. But those are exceptions to the rule, and monsters are *allowed* by the developers to break the rules all the time.

Few *Tiny* creatures that immediately comes to mind that have a reach larger than 0 ft are [Pseudodragons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/pseudodragon/), on their tail attack. Similarly, [wyrmling dragons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-white/white-dragon-wyrmling/) with their bite attacks. Both of those are attacks that have an arbitrarily larger reach than the creature's normal reach, even on creatures that are not Tiny, such as [adult dragons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-white/adult-white-dragon/).

Other than that, to attack a creature, a Tiny (or smaller) creature must **occupy the same space** as the target.

While the topic of unusual reach is foggy, we know that a Tiny creature with a longspear (reach) would allow her to attack an adjacent creature, as seen on [this post by James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=427?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#21334) but cannot attack its own square thanks to [this other post from James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=428?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#21369).